# recursively download from a website

Tags: wget, curl, download, web

I am trying to get images from a website url "`www.example.com/products`" in this products folder lots of subfolders there I need to download the products folder.

In the   www.example.com/products, www.example.com/products/subfolders, the image is

- www.example.com/products/subfolder1/image.jpg,
- www.example.com/products/subfolder2/image.jpg,
- www.example.com/products/subfolder3/image.jpg

How can I download the products folder with subfolders with data.

Comment: friends thanks for your replay ,, here this link "www.example.com/products" i want what the data exist in product folder i need a command for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
wget -nd -r -l1 -P /save/location -A jpeg,jpg http://www.example.com/products
```

**Explanation :**

`-nd` prevents the creation of a directory hierarchy (i.e. [no directories](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory-Options)).

`-r` enables recursive retrieval. See [Recursive Download](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download) for more information.

`-l1` Specify recursion maximum depth level. 1 for just this directory in your case it's `products`.

`-P` sets the directory prefix where all files and directories are saved to.

`-A` sets a whitelist for retrieving only certain file types. Strings and patterns are accepted, and both can be used in a comma separated list (as seen above). See [Types of Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Try `httrack(1)`, a web spider that is most useful for
creating local mirrors of entire web sites.

- Homepage: https://www.httrack.com/
- Manpage: http://www.httrack.com/html/httrack.man.html

The examples in the linked manpage should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -nH --page-requisites -R -nH -P mirrorDirectory https://example.com
```

where mirrorDirectory is the path of where you want to store the output.